# Database structure for a complex report form

Tags: database-design

I am trying to design a database for a report form. This form has 10 `Sections`. 
each section is related to a `Department`.

As we receive this report each section or report will be sent to corresponding Department.

form fields may contain numeric, date, string or texts. and some sections also define one-to-many relation.

I would like some suggestion should i define one table for the complete `Report` or a table for each `Section`?

What can be the pros and cons of each technique?

Answer (score 0):

With such free-form documents, best choice would be a document database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

If you're stuck with relational database, consider the more flexible schema:

- **REPORTS** [report_id PK]
- **SECTION_TYPES** [section_type_id PK, department_id FK]
- **SECTION_FIELDS** [section_field_id PK, section_type_id FK, field_type VARCHAR] - this defines fields to be filled for given section type. Field_type can be 'NUMBER', 'DATE', 'STRING', ...
- **REPORT_SECTIONS** [report_section_id PK, report_id FK, section_type_id INT, field_value VARCHAR] - actual sections in a given report, contains reference to section_type_id and field_value as varchar (to be cast to required field type by application).

This can be harder to set up, but will pay off as soon as the report/section layouts change (which is always sooner than you expect :))